# How to change the index data in Int64Index?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

Good morning.

I've a few dataframes with this shape:

```
df = 
    date  unicode_label
0      1           5000
1      2           3000
2      3           2500
```

And I want convert it to this:

```
df_result = 
date             1     2     3
(something)  
unicode_label  5000  3000  2500
```

Currently, mu code is the following:

```
df['aux'] = 0
df = df.pivot('aux', 'date', 'unicode_label')
```

Getting:

```
df =
date    1     2     3
aux
0    5000  3000  2500
```

It's really close, but I don't know how to set that in my 'unicode_label', due to it doesn't let me set df.index.values.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is set new column by `unicode_label` and use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df['aux'] = 'unicode_label'
df = df.pivot('aux', 'date', 'unicode_label').rename_axis('(something)')
print (df)
date              1     2     3
(something)                    
unicode_label  5000  3000  2500
```

If your solution cannot be changed use `rename`:

```
df['aux'] = 0
df = df.pivot('aux', 'date', 'unicode_label')
print (df)
date     1     2     3
aux                   
0     5000  3000  2500

df = df.rename_axis('(something)').rename({0:'unicode_label'})
print (df)
date              1     2     3
(something)                    
unicode_label  5000  3000  2500
```

Comment: Ouh, so simply and useful solution, thanks you very much, your help is always really appreciated!